# Use Pandas to join two dataframes on unique identifiers AND sum between dates specified in columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, sum, date-range

I'm using Pandas in Python 3.7 to process my data.

I have two dataframes, df_orders and df_sales, that look like the following:

df_orders:

```
StoreID    ProductID    OrderDate    Cover_Days
1234       0009998      20190510     2
1234       0009998      20190512     2
4321       0009998      20190510     2
4321       0087664      20190510     10
```

df_sales:

```
StoreID    ProductID    Date        TotalSales
1234       0009998      20190510    10
1234       0009998      20190511    10
4321       0009998      20190511    15
4321       0087664      20190511    50
4321       0087664      20190519    50
```

I want to join df_sales to df_orders on StoreID, ProductID, and a sum of TotalSales over the range OrderDate to OrderDate + Cover_Days such that I get the result:

df_result:

```
StoreID    ProductID    OrderDate    Cover_Days    Sum_TotalSales
1234       0009998      20190510     2             20
1234       0009998      20190512     2             0
4321       0009998      20190510     2             15
4321       0087664      20190510     10            100
```

The df_sales dataframe has around 5 million rows per day of sales so an efficient answer would obviously be preferable!

Thoughts?

**Edit:**

By "sum of TotalSales over the range OrderDate to OrderDate + Cover_Days", what I mean is I want to sum all sales meeting three conditions:

1. df_sales.ProductID = df_orders.ProductID, and
2. df_sales.StoreID = df_orders.StoreID, and
3. where df_sales.Date falls into the range of dates between df_orders.OrderDate (e.g. 20190510) and df_orders['OrderDate' + 'Cover_Days'] (e.g. 20190510+2 = 20190512).

The reason being that the order data has multiple entries for each unique StoreID + ProductID combination, each with different (non-overlapping) dates.

Comment: You asked two questions, not one. Both have been asked separately before. Have you searched?

Comment: sorry I didn't get this part: *sum of TotalSales over the range OrderDate to OrderDate + Cover_Days*. To get your expected result but not quite - with a simple sum of `Sum_TotalSales` - I'd use `merge()` and `groupby()`: ```df_orders.merge(df_sales, on=['StoreID', 'ProductID']).groupby(['StoreID', 'ProductID', 'OrderDate', 'Cover_Days'])['TotalSales'].sum().reset_index()```  This should get you started at least

Comment: @politicalscientist I don't think this will work since, during the merge, we aren't joining on a match of date ranges - this will lead to double counting of sales, right?

Comment: @cs95 I'm wondering what my two questions are? I'm asking about one join with several conditions. As for searching: if I hadn't done this, then during the process of posting a question StackOverflow effectively forces you to consider looking at similar questions anyway. Thus, categorically, yes I have searched.